# Почему не получается правильно задать Primary Key?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

Хочу сделать небольшое приложение, в котором необходимо сохранять объекты в бд, пробовал сохранять так, но получаю `SQLite Error 1: 'table clipboard has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied`, если задаю id как 0, то получаю `UNIQUE constraint failed` :

```
    internal static class ClipboardsDatabase
    {
        private static string pathToDB = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "clipboards.db");
        static ClipboardsDatabase()
        {
            Init();
        }

        private static async void Init()
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("clipboards.db", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={pathToDB}"))
            {
                con.Open();
                string initCmd = 
                    @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clipboard( 
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                    title TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    content TEXT NOT NULL)";

                SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(initCmd, con);
                createTable.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }

        public static void InsertClipboard(ClipboardModel clipboard)
        {
            using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={pathToDB}"))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCmd = new SqliteCommand();

                insertCmd.Connection = con;
                insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO clipboard VALUES(@title, @content)";//@id, 

                //insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
                insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", clipboard.Title);
                insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", clipboard.Content);

                insertCmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }

    //...

    }
```

Как я могу задать его правильно?

Comment: Забыли указать названия столбцов? `INSERT INTO clipboard (title, content) VALUES ....`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, спасибо

Comment: На заметку: [Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) не рекомендуется использовать. См. документацию: [primary key](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_primary_key) и последний пункт.